# find an xml tag and replace the tag name with python

Tags: python, xml, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

**The kml file i am parsing:** http://pastebin.com/kU5rPssk

I am looking for all of the `<name>` tags that match this regex `\<name\>(\d+ \@.*)\<\/name\>` and then manipulate the text of the tag.

Here is my code that I used to try to test the regex:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Open the KML file.
xmldoc = open('doc.kml', "r+")
soup = BeautifulSoup(xmldoc, "xml")

p = re.compile(r"\<name\>(\d+ \@.*)\<\/name\>")

result = re.findall(p, soup)

print result
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\regex_test.py", line 10, in <module>
result = re.findall(p, soup)
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the traceback! The problem is that you're passing the regex a `soup` object, not a string (or a buffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a regular expression to the [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) argument of [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('doc.kml'), 'xml')
for name in soup.find_all('name', text=re.compile("\d+ @.*")):
    print name
```

It prints:

```
<kml:name>13233 @ 2014-05-19 21:35:30 GMT (ACPU)</kml:name>
<kml:name>13233 @ 2014-05-19 21:36:30 GMT (ACPU)</kml:name>
<kml:name>13233 @ 2014-05-19 21:37:30 GMT (ACPU)</kml:name>
...
<kml:name>13233 @ 2014-05-19 22:28:30 GMT (ACPU)</kml:name>
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that! BeautifulSoup is, ahem, beautiful.

Comment: @alecxe Is this let's ask the same questions so many times in a day? =)

Comment: @hwnd yup, the strong deja vu feeling :)

Comment: You didn't need to escape the `@`, but you knew that already =)

Comment: @AdamSmith yeah, it makes this "soup" so beautiful and tasty :)

Comment: @technocon that should be pinging alecxe presumably :)